# Memory Leak in Custom List Type Using Template Class

Tags: c++, list, templates, memory-leaks

I am trying to create a custom list type in C++ using the C++ `template` feature, and I have gotten it to compile and run correctly for lists of different types of value, even lists of lists of values, however when I run the program with Valgrind I get a memory leak.

I have been staring at this one for ages but have not gotten any further to fixing it, though I am sure there is something blindingly obvious that I am missing that someone experienced can point out.

Here is my list type:

```cpp
template<typename listType>
class List {
public:
    listType *data;
    unsigned int listLength;

    List() {
        listLength = 0;
        data = (listType *) malloc(sizeof(listType));
    }

    explicit List(unsigned int len) {
        listLength = len;
        // I have tried freeing "data" here but that leads to more errors
        //  ---------------------- Valgrind says the leak is here ----------------------
        data = (listType *) malloc(sizeof(listType) * len);
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            data[i] = listType();
        }
    }

    List<listType> &operator=(const List<listType> &other) {
        if (this != &other) {
            listLength = other.listLength;
            data = (listType *) malloc(sizeof(listType) * other.listLength);
            memcpy(data, other.data, sizeof(listType) * other.listLength);
        }

        return *this;
    }

    ~List() {
        if (std::is_fundamental<listType>::value) {
            free(data);
        } else {
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {
                data[i].~listType();
            }
            free(data);
        }
    }

    listType &operator[](unsigned int index) const {
        return data[index];
    }
};
```

If anyone could explain how I can fix this issue and why it is happening that would be extremely helpful, as I have been stuck on this one for hours now.

Comment: `data = (listType *) malloc(sizeof(listType) * other.listLength);` in your copy ctor. ask yourself "what happened to memory pointed to by the target `data` member upon entry into that function?" You leaked it, and in so doing, the memory it referred to. Separate note: you would also *never* do this with `malloc` in the first place, as `listType` that requires non-trivial construction is going to lead to an entirely new set of problems you'd rather avoid.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but why do you use `malloc` in C++? Your constructors could be written in two lines with `new[]` and destructor with one line using `delete[]`.

Comment: I think these bad habits come from me originally learning C, and not fully understanding the nuances of C++ compared to it. These comments fixed the issue so I will answer this question with these points. Thanks!

Comment: Why not simply use `std::vector<listType>`?  You are attempting to reinvent the wheel, and making a lot of mistakes doing so.  Lack of copy constructor, the assignment operator leaking memory, usage of `memcpy` and `malloc`, improper usage of constructs such as explicitly calling the destructor, etc.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie This was simply a small outtake from the main program that does have all of the features you mention. And yes, I am reinventing the wheel, though I am just trying to learn the language and develop my programming skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As WhozCraig and Yksisarvinen pointed out in the comments, using `new[]` and `delete[]` as opposed to using the `malloc()` function allows the memory to be allocated and freed correctly, and the resulting code is shown below just in case it helps anybody:

```cpp
template<typename listType>
class List {
public:
    listType *data;
    unsigned int listLength;

    List() {
        listLength = 0;
        data = new listType[1];
    }

    explicit List(unsigned int len) {
        listLength = len;
        data = new listType[len];
    }

    List(const List<listType> &other) {
        listLength = other.listLength;
        data = new listType[other.listLength];
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {
            data[i] = other.data[i];
        }
    }

    List<listType> &operator=(const List<listType> &other) {
        if (this != &other) {
            listLength = other.listLength;
            delete[] data;
            data = new listType[other.listLength];
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {
                data[i] = other.data[i];
            }
        }

        return *this;
    }

    ~List() {
        delete[] data;
    }

    listType &operator[](unsigned int index) const {
        return data[index];
    }
};
```

Comment: The class still violates the rule of 3.  Where is the user-defined copy constructor?  You still have a call to `malloc` in your code?  And also, a simple `int main() { List<std::string> s; List<std::string> s2 = s1;}` causes all sorts of problems with the code you've posted as an answer.

Comment: I've edited the code so it now works for your examples. Hope there are no more obvious errors :)